# can you have multiple aggregators in a promQL query

Tags: prometheus, influxdb, promql, influxql, victoriametrics

In influxQL you can do queries with multiple aggregation functions like this:

```
SELECT MEAN(value), MIN(value) FROM measurement WHERE category= ...
```

In promQl you can specify an aggregation function as well, like Avg:

```
Avg by (server) (HttpStatusCodes{category = 'Api.ResponseStatus'})
```

but I wanted to know if you can do multiple aggregators in promQl just like in influxQL, something like this:

```
Avg, Max by (server) (HttpStatusCodes{category = 'Api.ResponseStatus'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following [MetricsQL](https://victoriametrics.github.io/MetricsQL.html) query:

```
with (m = HttpStatusCodes{category = 'Api.ResponseStatus'})
(
  alias(max(max_over_time(m)) by (server),  "max"),
  alias(sum(sum_over_time(m)) by (server) / sum(count_over_time(m)) by (server), "avg")
)
```